I trying to call png images but only one is not working
my code:
import Image from "next/image";

export default function LoginPage({ tipo }: { tipo: String }) {

    return (
        <div className="TelaLogin">
            <h1 className="Title">Entre</h1>
            <button><Image src={"/Public_Itens/Imagens/Default_Site_Img/github.png"} width={"100"} height={"100"} alt="github" /></button>
            <button><Image src={"/Public_Itens/Imagens/Default_Site_Img/facebook.png"} width={"100"} height={"100"} alt="facebook" /></button>
            <button><Image src={"/Public_Itens/Imagens/Default_Site_Img/gmail.png"} width={"100"} height={"100"} alt="gmail" /></button>
            <button><Image src={"/Public_Itens/Imagens/Default_Site_Img/spotify.png"} width={"100"} height={"100"} alt="spotify" /></button>
            <button><Image src={"/Public_Itens/Imagens/Default_Site_Img/linkedin.png"} width={"100"} height={"100"} alt="linkdin" /></button>
            <br />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email"></input>
            <br />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Senha"></input>
        </div>
    )
}

the error I receive:

⨯ The requested resource isn't a valid image for
/Public_Itens/Imagens/Default_Site_Img/gmail.png received text/html;
charset=utf-8

all images are working less the gmail.png.
info:
yes I have a png archive in the same folder than others

It seems that your image gmail.png may actually be a text file. This can happen when the server you got the image from decides to reply in HTML instead, e.g. because it thinks you're hotlinking an image, or because of some server error. I bet if you open up gmail.png in a text editor you'll see what I mean.
